# Header Files with VS code "C"

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Good afternoon everyone,
I was wondering if someone can advise me on how to link header files when they are in different sub-file directory.

[image]

Comment: `calculations.h` versus `calculationS.h`?

Comment: And please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: calculations.h I have changed all of them to calculationS.h

Comment: If you work in Visual Studio, then you need to open the project properties, find Configuration Properties->C/C++->General. Next, find the item Additional Include Directories In it to specify the path to your folder where your header files are located. Then you can include header files through angle brackets #include <myheader.h>

Or you can not include the folder in Additional Include Directories, but specify your file relative to the source file, for example #include "../Myheaders/myheader.h" But then already in the usual buckets.

Comment: what do you mean by "link"? do you mean "include"? is the problem intellisense or actual compilation?

Answer (score 0):

In your `test_c.c` file, you need to go up one level to get into the `c` directory, then go down a level into the `Includes` directory. From there, you can include your `calculationS.h` file. In code, this would like like:

```c
#include "../Includes/calculationS.h
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's strange, I tried putting all the files into the same directory and using #include "calculationS.h" this also didn't work

Comment: Could you provide the compiler error please?

Comment: I have moved all the files "calculationS.c", "calculationS.h" and test_c.c to the same file "Test_C and the compiler gives me this:                                        *  Executing task: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -Wall -Wextra -g3 c:\Users\dp153060\Desktop\Wizard_Projects\C\Test_C\test_C.c -o c:\Users\dp153060\Desktop\Wizard_Projects\C\Test_C\output\test_C.exe 

C:\Users\dp153060\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQPAKL1.o: In function `main':
c:/Users/dp153060/Desktop/Wizard_Projects/C/Test_C/test_c.c:9: undefined reference to `add'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: After reviewing the screenshot again, it seems like you spelled your header file differently in `test_c.c` and in `calculationS.c`. One with a capital and one with a lowercase "s" at the end. Make sure you spell your file name correctly try if it works.

Comment: I have changed the names from calculations.c to calculationS.c and it still doesn't work

Comment: I think I have found the issue! When I remove most of the folder names from your compilation command, it becomes clear why your compilation failed:
Your issue is that you are **only** compiling `test_C.c` and not giving the compiler the other files. If you are using the VS Code Run C++ file option, I suggest you take a look at how to make a configuration for it (tutorials on youtube). If you want to just do it from the CLI, run `gcc - Wall -Wextra -g3 test_C.c calculations.c -o test_C.exe`. This should resolve your issue!

Comment: Is it possible to change the "tasks.json" to do the same thing ? "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g3",
                "-Wall",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],

Comment: That was what I meant by suggesting to learn how to make configurations. Most of the times when I code in C/C++, I simply use Visual Studio, which *usually* comes with everything working out of the box, or I use a Makefile. I am not familiar with the `tasks.json` from VSC, so I can't help you with that unfortunately. If your compilation works, I think you can figure the tasks.json part out with tutorials from youtube or google.

Comment: `undefined reference` always means a linking error - i.e. you aren't telling the compiler about all the source files.  This has nothing to do with header file includes.